# Lexeme vs. Lemma

Tags: terminology, computational-linguistics

A *lexeme* to me has always been a fairly abstract entity and a *lemma* a concrete form that is often used to represent an lexeme.

It is surprising to me, then, that the process in NLP is almost always called *lemmatization*<sub>(400k ghits)</sub> rather than *lexemization*<sub>(840 ghits)</sub> or *lexematization*<sub>(128 ghits)</sub> (a search at my university’s library reveals a similiar difference of 2445:1:1)  While I can understand that if an analysis arrives at a *lemma* by way of various rules similar to destemming applied to a text string it may be the most appropriate term, at a certain point (for instance, once an abstract entity in a database, or attached with some other metadata such as part of speech), shouldn't the term be instead *lexeme*?

Is there a particular reason that the term *lemma* seems to be virtually universally used in much of NLP literature to mean both *lemma* and *lexeme*?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are differences between lemma and lexeme in NLP. Lemmatisation may tell you that some lemma is *bank* but you need another process (word sense disambiguation) to discriminate between *bank (of a river)* and *bank (where you put money)*. There are also **multi word expressions** (MWEs) that count as multiple lemmas but may count as a single lexeme.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.  In my mind, it seems fairly easy enough to determine the POS (at least for the language I'm working on), hence distinguishing *bank* (a noun) from *bank* (a verb).  That seemed to be starting to cross the threshold between the two, but indeed I didn't consider the multiple lexemes for a single POS which would require a second pass